# How we can make custom modulle for review and star rating functionality in my custom admin and frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, module, review, ratings

How we can make **custom module** for  **review and star rating functionality** in my custom admin and **frontend**.

Comment: Review and star rating is provided by default in Magento. Why do you want it by custom module?